# Input fields and dropzone taking previous state values on api call for file stream in React

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, state

I am having two pages one is Update user and second is User profile, the Updae user edits the user in userlist while the User profile edit the current logged in User,
The problem I am encountering is that when I open the Update User and I am getting the correct data in the input fields and in the file dropzone.
But when I go from this Update user page to the User profile the input fields in User profile should contain the current logged in user but I am getting the user data from the Update user page and same for the FileDropzone.

I debugged the code and what I observed is that api call to get stream is called twice first with the previous data second the current data. So the previous api call was responding after the current one so the file that was set is the previous one.

Below I am providing the funtions and hooks I am using to update the state.

```
  const setUserDetailState = useCallback(async () => {
    if (isJSONString(userByIdDetails.data)) {
      const data = JSON.parse(userByIdDetails.data);
      console.log(" userByIdDetails profile data ", data);

      const newData = {
        username: {
          value: data.UserName,
          error: "",
        },
        email: {
          value: data.Email,
          error: "",
        },
        mobile: {
          value: data.Mobile,
          error: "",
        },
        password: {
          value: "", // TODO:: password to be set
          error: "",
        },
        updatedAt: {
          value: (data.UpdatedAt != null && data.UpdatedAt != undefined) ? data.UpdatedAt : "",
          error: "",
        },
        role: {
          value: data.Role,
          error: "",
        },
        designation: {
          value: data.Designation,
          error: "",
        },
        organizationName: {
          value: data.OrganizationName,
          error: "",
        },
        profileImage: {
          value: "",
          error: "",
        },
        status: {
          value: data.Status,
          error: "",
        },
      };


      setDefaultUrl(data.ProfileImage);

      setUserData((previousData) => ({
        ...previousData,
        ...newData,
      }));
      // call the stream api to get the tram for the default url
      if (data.ProfileImage) {

        try {
          // Define the body parameters
          const requestBody = {
            fileName: data.ProfileImage,
            module: "ProfileImage"
          };

          // Make the API call
          const response = await axios.post(
            `${baseUrl}/api/Storage/GetFileStream`,
            requestBody,
            {
              responseType: 'blob', // Set response type to blob
              headers: {
                "Content-Type": "application/json", // Update content type to JSON
              },
            }
          );

          if (response.data) {
            // Assuming the response contains the file stream data
            // console.log("responce  :")
            const fileStream = response.data;

            // Generate URL for the file stream
            const fileUrl = URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([fileStream]));
            // console.log("fileUrl  :", fileUrl)
            // Set the intro file display URL
            // setImageURl(fileUrl);
            setImageURl({
              url: fileUrl,
              type: extractFileType(data.ProfileImage),
              name: extractFileInfo(data.ProfileImage).name,
            });

          } else {
            // Handle API response errors
            console.error("File upload failed:");
          }
        } catch (error) {
          // Handle API call errors
          console.error("Error uploading file:", error);
        }
      }



      // // setImageURl(data.ProfileImageDisplay);
      // setDefaultUrl(data.ProfileImage);
      // // setProfieImage(data);

      // setUserData((previousData) => ({
      //   ...previousData,
      //   ...newData,
      // }));
    }
  }, [userByIdDetails]);


  useEffect(() => {
    if (userByIdDetails === null || userByIdDetails === undefined) return;

    if (!userID) return;

    setUserDetailState();
  }, [userByIdDetails]);
```

I have also used to clean up functions to reset the states

Please help me what solution and and should I use.